# Optimizing CUDA Kernel

Tags: c++, optimization, memory-management, cuda, nvidia

How can the following CUDA kernel be further optimized? or is it already optmized for its' purpose?

I was thinking maybe I can use `__constant__` memory in the host code for the arrays to be set with random numbers. Is this possible? I know it is read only memory so I am confused is to whether or not I can use constant memory instead of `__global__` memory.

```
   /*
 * CUDA kernel that will execute 100 threads in parallel
 * and will populate these parallel arrays with 100 random numbers
 * array size = 100.
*/

__global__ void initializeArrays(float* posx, float* posy,float* rayon, float* veloc,
                                float* opacity ,float* angle, unsigned char* color, int height,
                                int width, curandState* state, size_t pitch){

    int idx =  blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    curandState localState = state[idx];

    posx[idx] = (float)(curand_normal(&localState)*width);
    posy[idx] = (float)(curand_normal(&localState)*height);
    rayon[idx] = (float)(10 + curand_normal(&localState)*50);
    angle[idx] = (float)(curand_normal(&localState)*360);
    veloc[idx] = (float)(curand_uniform(&localState)*20 - 10);
    color[idx*pitch] = (unsigned char)(curand_normal(&localState)*255);
    color[(idx*pitch)+1] = (unsigned char)(curand_normal(&localState)*255);
    color[(idx*pitch)+2] = (unsigned char)(curand_normal(&localState)*255);
    opacity[idx] = (float)(0.3f + 1.5f *curand_normal(&localState));

    __syncthreads();
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `__syncthreads`?

Comment: For which architecture do you need the optimization? Fermi? Kepler?

Comment: I need the optimization for a graphics card with compute capability of 1.2. I think that is Fermi?

Comment: Why don't you use a multiple of the warp size (i.e. 32) for the number of threads? Also, did you use the NVIDIA profiling tools (e.g. `nvvp`)? Did you compile with optimization flags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try making 2D threads block and make each thread only performs one operation.
Consider a kernel like this:

```
__global__ void initializeArrays(float* posx, float* posy,float* rayon, float* veloc,
                            float* opacity ,float* angle, unsigned char* color, int height,
                            int width, curandState* state, size_t pitch){

int idx =  blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int idy = threadIdx.y;
curandState localState = state[idy][idx];

    switch(idy)
    {
        case 0:
            posx[idx] = (float)(curand_normal(&localState)*width);
            break;
        case 1:
            posy[idx] = (float)(curand_normal(&localState)*height);
            break;
        case 2:
            rayon[idx] = (float)(10 + curand_normal(&localState)*50);
            break;
        case 3:
            angle[idx] = (float)(curand_normal(&localState)*360);
            break;
        case 4:
            veloc[idx] = (float)(curand_uniform(&localState)*20 - 10);
            break;
        case 5:
            color[idx*pitch] = (unsigned char)(curand_normal(&localState)*255);
            break;
        case 6:
            color[(idx*pitch)+1] = (unsigned char)(curand_normal(&localState)*255);
            break;
        case 7:
            color[(idx*pitch)+2] = (unsigned char)(curand_normal(&localState)*255);
            break;
        case 8:
            opacity[idx] = (float)(0.3f + 1.5f *curand_normal(&localState));
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    __syncthreads();
}
```

This may actually give you some speed up.